# UIManagedDocument & processing data in background thread

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, uimanageddocument

Would like to know what's the best/suggested way to process UIManagedDocument (Core) data in a background thread.

Most questions are about adding new data in a background thread - I want to simply read them.

I tried using the parentContext (doc.managedContext.parentContext) but it does not have all the updates (insertions, deletions, etc) until the document is 'saved'

As I have no control when then document is actually saved I'm unsure how to push these changes to the parentContext.

I also tried using a MOC with its own private queue with similar results.

Any advice please?

Thank you